# How to automatically install all dependendicies in cpan Bio

Tags: perl, cpan

Hel lo, I'm actually trying to install a perl package called HMMCleaner

I ran for that the command:

```
cpan Bio::MUST::Apps::HmmCleaner
```

but during the process I got several messages telling : `Warning: prerequisite something 0 not found.`

Here is a head of the output :

```
(/beegfs/data/me/myconda) me@pbil-deb:/beegfs/data/me/TOOLS/Bio-MUST-Apps-HmmCleaner-0.180750/bin$ cpan Test::Harness::Straps
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
Reading '/beegfs/home/me/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 14 Feb 2020 09:41:03 GMT
Running install for module 'Test::Harness::Straps'
Fetching with LWP:
http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/MS/MSCHWERN/Test-Harness-Straps-0.30.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/MS/MSCHWERN/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for /beegfs/home/me/.cpan/sources/authors/id/M/MS/MSCHWERN/Test-Harness-Straps-0.30.tar.gz ok
Configuring M/MS/MSCHWERN/Test-Harness-Straps-0.30.tar.gz with Build.PL
Test::Harness::Straps is provided for backwards compatibility only.
No further development is planned.  No bugs will be fixed.

For customizable TAP parsing please use L<TAP::Parser> instead.

Created MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Creating new 'Build' script for 'Test-Harness-Straps' version '0.30'
  MSCHWERN/Test-Harness-Straps-0.30.tar.gz
  /beegfs/data/me/myconda/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site -- OK
Running Build for M/MS/MSCHWERN/Test-Harness-Straps-0.30.tar.gz
Building Test-Harness-Straps
  MSCHWERN/Test-Harness-Straps-0.30.tar.gz
  ./Build -- OK
Running Build test
t/00compile.t ...... 1/5 # Testing Test::Harness::Straps 0.30 under Perl 5.026002 and Test::More 1.302073
t/00compile.t ...... ok   
t/callback.t ....... ok     
t/point-parse.t .... ok     
t/point.t .......... ok     
t/strap-analyze.t .. ok       
t/strap.t .......... ok     
All tests successful.
Files=6, Tests=425,  9 wallclock secs ( 0.12 usr  0.04 sys +  0.98 cusr  0.67 csys =  1.81 CPU)
Result: PASS
  MSCHWERN/Test-Harness-Straps-0.30.tar.gz
  ./Build test -- OK
Running Build install
Building Test-Harness-Straps
Installing /beegfs/home/me/perl5/lib/perl5/Test/Harness/Assert.pm
Installing /beegfs/home/me/perl5/lib/perl5/Test/Harness/Straps.pm
Installing /beegfs/home/me/perl5/lib/perl5/Test/Harness/Results.pm
Installing /beegfs/home/me/perl5/lib/perl5/Test/Harness/Point.pm
Installing /beegfs/home/me/perl5/lib/perl5/Test/Harness/Iterator.pm
Installing /beegfs/home/me/perl5/man/man3/Test::Harness::Point.3
Installing /beegfs/home/me/perl5/man/man3/Test::Harness::Assert.3
Installing /beegfs/home/me/perl5/man/man3/Test::Harness::Results.3
Installing /beegfs/home/me/perl5/man/man3/Test::Harness::Iterator.3
Installing /beegfs/home/me/perl5/man/man3/Test::Harness::Straps.3
  MSCHWERN/Test-Harness-Straps-0.30.tar.gz
  ./Build install  -- OK
(/beegfs/data/me/myconda) me@pbil-deb:/beegfs/data/me/TOOLS/Bio-MUST-Apps-HmmCleaner-0.180750/bin$ cpan Bio::MUST::Apps::HmmCleaner
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
Reading '/beegfs/home/me/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 14 Feb 2020 09:41:03 GMT
Running install for module 'Bio::MUST::Apps::HmmCleaner'
Checksum for /beegfs/home/me/.cpan/sources/authors/id/A/AR/ARNODF/Bio-MUST-Apps-HmmCleaner-0.180750.tar.gz ok
Configuring A/AR/ARNODF/Bio-MUST-Apps-HmmCleaner-0.180750.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite Bio::FastParsers::Hmmer 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Bio::MUST::Core 0.180230 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Bio::MUST::Core::Ali 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Bio::MUST::Core::Constants 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Bio::MUST::Core::GeneticCode::Factory 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Bio::MUST::Core::IdList 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Bio::MUST::Core::Seq 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Bio::MUST::Core::SeqMask 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Bio::MUST::Core::Utils 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Bio::MUST::Drivers 0.180270 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Bio::MUST::Drivers::Hmmer::Model::Temporary 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite IPC::System::Simple 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Smart::Comments 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite aliased 0 not found.
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Bio::MUST::Apps::HmmCleaner
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  ARNODF/Bio-MUST-Apps-HmmCleaner-0.180750.tar.gz
  /beegfs/data/me/myconda/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for A/AR/ARNODF/Bio-MUST-Apps-HmmCleaner-0.180750.tar.gz
----     Unsatisfied dependencies detected during    ----
---- ARNODF/Bio-MUST-Apps-HmmCleaner-0.180750.tar.gz ----
    Bio::FastParsers::Hmmer [requires]
    Bio::MUST::Core [requires]
    Bio::MUST::Core::Ali [requires]
    Bio::MUST::Core::Constants [requires]
    Bio::MUST::Core::GeneticCode::Factory [requires]
    Bio::MUST::Core::IdList [requires]
    Bio::MUST::Core::Seq [requires]
    Bio::MUST::Core::SeqMask [requires]
    Bio::MUST::Core::Utils [requires]
    Bio::MUST::Drivers [requires]
    Bio::MUST::Drivers::Hmmer::Model::Temporary [requires]
    IPC::System::Simple [requires]
    Smart::Comments [requires]
    aliased [requires]
Running install for module 'Bio::FastParsers::Hmmer'
Checksum for /beegfs/home/me/.cpan/sources/authors/id/D/DB/DBAURAIN/Bio-FastParsers-0.180470.tar.gz ok
Configuring D/DB/DBAURAIN/Bio-FastParsers-0.180470.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite Const::Fast 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Exporter::Easy 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Smart::Comments 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite XML::Bare 0.53 not found.
Warning: prerequisite aliased 0 not found.
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Bio::FastParsers
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  DBAURAIN/Bio-FastParsers-0.180470.tar.gz
  /beegfs/data/me/myconda/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for D/DB/DBAURAIN/Bio-FastParsers-0.180470.tar.gz
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
---- DBAURAIN/Bio-FastParsers-0.180470.tar.gz ----
    Const::Fast [requires]
    Exporter::Easy [requires]
    Smart::Comments [requires]
    XML::Bare [requires]
    aliased [requires]
Running install for module 'Const::Fast'
```

So I wondered if there were a possibility to direclty allow cpan to install all the dependency needed?

I ask because I get the following error message when trying to execute a script using Bio::MUST::Apps::HMMCleaner.

```
Can't locate Smart/Comments.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Smart::Comments module) (@INC contains:
    /beegfs/home/me/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    /beegfs/home/me/perl5/lib/perl5
    /beegfs/data/me/myconda/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    /beegfs/data/me/myconda/lib/site_perl/5.26.2
    /beegfs/data/me/myconda/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    /beegfs/data/me/myconda/lib/5.26.2
    .
) at HmmCleaner.pl line 16. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at HmmCleaner.pl line 16.
```

(Line breaks added for readability.)

Some debugging information:

```
$ set | grep ^PERL
PERL5LIB=/beegfs/home/me/perl5/lib/perl5
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=/beegfs/home/me/perl5
PERL_MB_OPT='--install_base "/beegfs/home/me/perl5"'
PERL_MM_OPT=INSTALL_BASE=/beegfs/home/me/perl5

$ echo 'o conf' | cpan | grep -P '^\s*(make|mbuild)'
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
    make               [/usr/bin/X11/make]
    make_arg           []
    make_install_arg   []
    make_install_make_command [/usr/bin/X11/make]
    makepl_arg         [INSTALLDIRS=site]
    mbuild_arg         []
    mbuild_install_arg []
    mbuild_install_build_command [./Build]
    mbuildpl_arg       [--installdirs site]

$ which cpan
/beegfs/data/me/myconda/bin/cpan

$ head -n 1 "$( which cpan )"
#!/beegfs/data/me/myconda/bin/perl

$ which perl
/beegfs/data/me/myconda/bin/perl

$ cpan Smart::Comments
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
Reading '/beegfs/home/me/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 14 Feb 2020 09:41:03 GMT
Running install for module 'Smart::Comments'
Checksum for /beegfs/home/me/.cpan/sources/authors/id/N/NE/NEILB/Smart-Comments-1.06.tar.gz ok
Configuring N/NE/NEILB/Smart-Comments-1.06.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Smart::Comments
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  NEILB/Smart-Comments-1.06.tar.gz
  /beegfs/data/me/myconda/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for N/NE/NEILB/Smart-Comments-1.06.tar.gz
cp lib/Smart/Comments.pm blib/lib/Smart/Comments.pm
Manifying 1 pod document
  NEILB/Smart-Comments-1.06.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/X11/make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/beegfs/data/me/myconda/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00.load.t ................. 1/1 # Testing Smart::Comments 1.06
t/00.load.t ................. ok   
t/assert.t .................. ok   
t/brackets.t ................ ok    
t/c_like_for_loop.t ......... ok   
t/check.t ................... ok   
t/confirm.t ................. ok   
t/ensure.t .................. ok   
t/ENV_0.t ................... ok   
t/ENV_1.t ................... ok   
t/ENV_str.t ................. ok   
t/insist.t .................. ok   
t/labelled_perlish_loop.t ... ok   
t/message.t ................. ok   
t/perlish_for.t ............. ok   
t/perlish_for_percentage.t .. ok   
t/pod-coverage.t ............ skipped: Test::Pod::Coverage 1.04 required for testing POD coverage
t/pod.t ..................... skipped: Test::Pod 1.14 required for testing POD
t/require.t ................. ok   
t/selective.t ............... ok   
t/simple_perlish_for.t ...... ok   
t/var.t ..................... ok   
t/verify.t .................. ok   
t/while.t ................... ok   
t/while_num.t ............... ok   
All tests successful.
Files=24, Tests=119, 19 wallclock secs ( 0.13 usr  0.08 sys +  2.93 cusr  1.45 csys =  4.59 CPU)
Result: PASS
  NEILB/Smart-Comments-1.06.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/X11/make test -- OK
Running make install
Manifying 1 pod document
Installing /beegfs/home/me/perl5/lib/perl5/Smart/Comments.pm
Installing /beegfs/home/me/perl5/man/man3/Smart::Comments.3
Appending installation info to /beegfs/home/me/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/perllocal.pod
  NEILB/Smart-Comments-1.06.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/X11/make install  -- OK

$ perl -e'use Smart::Comments; print "ok\n"'
ok
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly what it does.

For example, `Warning: prerequisite Bio::FastParsers::Hmmer 0 not found.` means an unsatisfied dependency for version 0 or higher of the Bio::FastParsers::Hmmer module was encountered. The Bio::MUST::Apps::HmmCleaner module is provided by the `Bio-FastParsers` distribution, and you can clearly see `Bio-FastParsers` being installed.

Technically, this is configurable.

```
$ echo 'o conf init prerequisites_policy' | cpan
...
The CPAN module can detect when a module which you are trying to build
depends on prerequisites. If this happens, it can build the
prerequisites for you automatically ('follow'), ask you for
confirmation ('ask'), or just ignore them ('ignore').  Choosing
'follow' also sets PERL_AUTOINSTALL and PERL_EXTUTILS_AUTOINSTALL for
"--defaultdeps" if not already set.

Please set your policy to one of the three values.

 <prerequisites_policy>
Policy on building prerequisites (follow, ask or ignore)? [follow] follow
...
```

But the default value is `follow`, and your output shows if it's following dependencies.

Comment: Ok but when I try to execute the .pl file I get : `Can't locate Smart/Comments.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Smart::Comments module) (@INC contains: /beegfs/home/me/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /beegfs/home/me/perl5/lib/perl5 /beegfs/data/me/myconda/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /beegfs/data/me/myconda/lib/site_perl/5.26.2 /beegfs/data/me/myconda/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /beegfs/data/me/myconda/lib/5.26.2 .) at HmmCleaner.pl line 16.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at HmmCleaner.pl line 16.`

Comment: Please provide the output of `set | grep ^PERL; echo 'o conf' | cpan | grep -P '^\s*(make|mbuild)'; which cpan; head -n 1 "$( which cpan )"; which perl; cpan Smart::Comments; perl -e'use Smart::Comments'` (Add it to your question.)

Comment: There's no error in output you added. Smart::Comment was successfully installed and loaded. If you still get an error from `HmmCleaner.pl`, you are using a different `perl` and/or a different environment (one without `PERL5LIB` set as you showed).

Comment: How can I see what perl5lib environment I'm using instead of the /beegfs/home/me/perl5/lib/perl5?

Comment: We used `set | grep ^PERL` above, but `echo "$PERL5LIB"` would also do the trick.

Comment: Ok I see but I do not really get where is the issue here. In fact I'm actually on a conda environement, in order to install HMMCleaner i used : `/beegfs/data/me/myconda/bin/cpan Bio::MUST::Apps::HmmCleaner`. So if I understand well how can I know if I use the wrong perl or if the environment I'm using is wrong ? Should I change the PERL5LIB to match one present in conda env? In this cas how can I locat this lib environment?

Comment: Re "*how can I know if I use the wrong perl*", You should be using `cpan` installed by the `perl` you are using. You can check the first line of the `cpan` file. That's why I asked you to run `head -n 1 "$( which cpan )"`.

Comment: Re "*if the environment I'm using is wrong*", If you tell the module's installer to install the module in a non-standard location, but don't tell `perl` to look for the modules there. That's why I asked you to run `set | grep ^PERL; echo 'o conf' | cpan | grep -P '^\s*(make|mbuild)'`.

Comment: In the environment you ran the commands, it shows that you are instructing both ExtUtils::MakeMaker (via env var `PERL_MM_OPT`) and Module::Build (via env var `PERL_MB_OPT`) to install into `/beegfs/home/me/perl5`, and you tell Perl to look for modules in there (via env var `PERL5LIB`). This is good.

Comment: I get : `Can't locate Bio/MUST/Apps/HmmCleaner.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Bio::MUST::Apps::HmmCleaner module) (@INC contains: /beegfs/home/me/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /beegfs/home/me/perl5/lib/perl5 /beegfs/data/me/myconda/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /beegfs/data/me/myconda/lib/site_perl/5.26.2 /beegfs/data/me/myconda/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /beegfs/data/me/myconda/lib/5.26.2 .) at /beegfs/data/me/TOOLS/HCLean/bin/HmmCleaner.pl line 18.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /beegfs/data/me/TOOLS/HCLean/bin/HmmCleaner.pl line 18.`

Comment: And? I've already told you what commands to use to debug this. Run them in the same environment that's giving you them problems this time!